# Is there a way to share data between Flask server and a thread created by it(without using globals?)

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading, prometheus

I have a Flask server which has a `metrics()`  endpoint(which is a consumer for a variable called `count_var`).
Prometheus scrapes data by calling this metrics() endpoint every 10s
There is a producer thread called `run_job` created by this server at the beginning with the following code, which runs every 30s to populate this `count_var`
All of the following code is in test.py

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    def run_job():
        while True:
            try:
                app.logger.info("collect metrics....")
                getMetrics() 
            except Exception as e:
                app.logger.info("Exception {}".format(e))
                pass
            time.sleep(30)
    thread = threading.Thread(target=run_job)
    thread.start()

    app.logger.info('start server')
    app.run('0.0.0.0')
```

I have working `getMetrics()` code which declares global variable as following(and the variable is consumed in `metrics()` and displayed in prometheus correctly)

```
import threading
count_var = 0
app = Flask(__name__)
def getMetrics():
    global count_var
    # fill count_var here
```

The consumer for this code is the metrics() endpoint

```
@app.route("/metrics", methods=['GET'])
def metrics():
    PROMCOUNT.set(count_var)
    return 
    Response(prometheus_client.generate_latest(registry), 
     mimetype=CONTENT_TYPE_LATEST)
```

I want to avoid using global variables completely. I looked at Queue to share `count_var` between process and thread, however rate at which data is produced and consumed is different(also `getMetrics()` might error out or block and then queue would be empty when `metrics()` endpoint is called)
I also looked at `multiprocessing` but from the examples I saw you need to start processes sharing data with `multiprocessing.Process`...I can not use it to create the consumer since that's a REST endpoint

Comment: Is `count_var` used for anything other than responding to the `/metrics` route? It's not clear exactly what you mean by *"avoid using global variables completely"*, because `app` and `PROMCOUNT` are both also global variables.

Comment: That's a good point but those global variables are not shared between threads/processes. `count_var` isn't used anywhere except in /metrics route. And it is only updated inside the `run_job` thread. I want to add locking to this code and wanted to check if there is any way other than using global variables to share